# Changes are not applying to AngularJS view file

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS as my front-end, below is my HTML file

```
<div >
<div class="modal-dialog ">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <button type="button" ng-click='cancel()' class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{alert.summary}}</h4>
            </div>
            <form name="alertForm" novalidate>
                <div ng-if="!displayMap">
                    <alert ng-if='displayAlertMsg' type="alertMsg.type">{{alertMsg.message}}</alert>
                    <input type="hidden" ng-model="alert.source" />

                    <div class="field-box">
                        <span class="checkboxLabel">Public:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="checkbox" id='updateType' ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-model="alert.publicAlert"></input>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field-box">
                        <label>qweqwName:</label>
                        <input class="span5" id='updateName' ng-model="alert.summary" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="field-box">
                        <label>Notes:</label>
                        <textarea id='updateNotes' ng-model="alert.details" rows="2" required ></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="span3" style="margin-left: 0px;">
                        <div class="field-box">
                            <label>Priority:</label>
                            <select ng-model="updatePriority" ng-options="p.name for p in priorities" ng-change='updateP(updatePriority)'></select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field-box">
                            <label>Status:</label>
                            <select ng-model="updateState" ng-options="s.name for s in statusList" ng-change="updateS(updateState)"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                   <div id="alertmap-buttons" class="span2 no-margin">
                        <button id="alert-add-location" class="btn btn-default pull-left" ng-click="displayMap = !displayMap"><span ng-if="!displayMap">Add Location</span><span ng-if="displayMap">Done</span></button>
                        <button id="alert-cancel-location" class="btn btn-danger" ng-if="displayMap">Cancel</button>
                   </div>

                    <div id="latlng-label" class='span3 pull-right no-margin'>
                        <div class="pull-left"><label class="latlng-label">lat: {{alert.latitude}}</label></div>
                        <div class="pull-right"><label class="latlng-label">long: {{alert.longitude}}</label></div>
                    </div>

                <!--Select Coords from map-->
                <!--Google Map Directive-->
                <div ng-init="displayMap = false" ng-if="displayMap">


                    <google-map class="create-alert-map angular-google-map-container" center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom"
                                draggable='true'
                                events="mapEvents">

                        <markers models="themarkers"
                                 coords="'self'"
                                 >

                        </markers>



                    </google-map>
                </div>
                <!--Lat and Long
                <input placeholder="Latitude"  class="span2" id='updateLat' ng-model="alert.latitude" />
                <input style="float: right" placeholder="Longitude" class="span2" id='updateLong' ng-model="alert.longitude" /-->


            </form>


        </div>
        <div ng-if="!displayMap" class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="alertForm.$invalid">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This file is given to me by client and he want some CSS changes etc in that. But when I try to edit the file nothing is happening to the modal dialog box, for example if I change button text from Save to Submit it's not applying in the file. How come this???

If this information is not enough I can give controller JS file also. Thanks..

Comment: Did you tried clearing the cache in the browser.

Comment: Yes I have cleared the cache but no use.

Comment: Sure about you are editing the correct file?

Comment: After checking everything only I have posted here

Comment: A server side cache could be active, always serving you the same file.